# FROM dockerimage:latest pulls wrong image

Tags: docker, gitlab

I have a client-web/base image I build using gitlab ci pipeline:

- latest c4fba30df  204.03 MiB  6 days ago
- version_2 c4fba30df 204.03 MiB 6 days ago
- version_1 7904a77c0 153.69 MiB 2 months ago

these are the images in my docker repository: as you can see, the image with tag latest, is actually the latest image, having the same image id (c4fba30df) as the image with tag version_2.

I build another image that is built on top of base image:

```
FROM gitlab.faccousa.net:4567/faccos/client-web/base:latest
...
...
...
```

Yesterday, I built the above image file and it looks like it happened the following:

```
Step 1/6 : FROM gitlab.faccousa.net:4567/faccos/client-web/base:latest
  ---> 7904a77c0
```

But 7904a77c0 is the version_1, so the older image id.

Am I doing something wrong with the latest tag?

I know latest is misused by many people, but in this case I feel I have a CI the always builds my base image and tags it twice with:

- actual tag
- latest tag

Comment: have you tried `docker build --no-cache`?

Comment: I am doing docker build --no-cache:
docker build --no-cache --file dockerfile.services --tag $IMAGE_TAG_SERVICES:latest --tag $TAG --label version=$DATE .

Comment: Im suspecting the CI machine is not pulling image, could you add a step before the build to remove the latest image locally? `docker rmi gitlab.faccousa.net:4567/faccos/client-web/base:latest` if this fixes you can also try `docker build with --pull`

Comment: There's no need to run the `rmi`. All you need is the `pull` command. Doing the `rmi` will force a new pull every time even if you already had the image local, slowing down the build and adding unnecessary network traffic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you `docker run` an image, or if a Dockerfile is built `FROM` an image, and Docker thinks it already has the image locally, it will use the image it already has.  In your case, since you already have a `...:latest` version, Docker just uses it; it doesn't ever check that there might be a different version of the image with the same tag elsewhere.

The most reliable approach to this is to never use the `:latest` tag anywhere:

```
FROM gitlab.faccousa.net:4567/faccos/client-web/base:version_2
```

If you have a lot of dependent images and the base image changes at all regularly, though, maintaining this can become a hassle.

Another option is to tell [`docker build`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/) to try to `--pull` the base image every time

```
docker build --pull -t ... .
```

with the downsides that this build will fail if the remote repository is unavailable, and builds will take somewhat longer even if the base image hasn't changed.

Answer (score -2):

does base is your project name?

> gitlab.example.com:port/user/projectname:latest

here's the full [guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-build-docker-images-and-host-a-docker-image-repository-with-gitlab)

its normal that your version_2 and latest have the same image id